# Finding a lowest value in a list by name

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find the lowest price in a list. Problem is I'm looking for the lowest price for a specific name(Names are not the same so I have to specify when I'm looking for the lowest price).

```
 public class Sandelys : IComparable<Sandelys>, IEquatable<Sandelys>
{
    public int Nr{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Ammount { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

...
}
```

Here's my method

```
    protected List<Sandelys> FormuotiUzsakyma(List<Sandelys> sandelys, Uzsakymas uzsk)
        {
            var query = sandelys.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                                    .Select(grp => new
                                    {
                                        Name = grp.Key,
                                        Min = grp.Min(t=> t.Price)
                                    });
//Here I'm trying to find the lowest price by name but it returns null

            var min = sandelys.Min(r => r.Price);
    //This finds the lowest price but it's in the whole list, not by a specific name
            return sandelys;
        }
```

Comment: Also it should return the whole object in this case `Sandelys`.

Comment: You can edit with the `edit` link below your post. It looks like your first attempt is very close; what is wrong with it?

Comment: So it should return a list with one sandelys in it or just the sandelys object? I ask because I don't see the point of returning a list unless it has multiple items in it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can't tell you what's exactly wrong cause I'm just learning linq but when I tried debugging var `current` stays null

Comment: @BlakeThingstad It should only return the Sandelys object which has the same name and the lowest price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the lowest price for a specific name, you can use a `Where` clause to filter on the `Name` property, then use `OrderBy` to order the matching items by the `Price` property, and then return the `First` one (which will be the lowest price).

Note these methods require `using System.Linq;`

```
private static Sandelys GetLowestPriceByName(List<Sandelys> sandelys, string name)
{
    return sandelys?.Where(s => s.Name == name).OrderBy(s => s.Price).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem! I only changed `FirstOrDefault()` to `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

> it should only return the Sandelys object which has the same name and the lowest price

I would create a dictionary for this

```
var dict = sandelys.GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Min(y => y.Price));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're losing too much information in your `Select`. I'd recommend using the [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library for this, with its `MinBy` method. You can then have:

```
protected List<Sandelys> FormuotiUzsakyma(List<Sandelys> sandelys, Uzsakymas uzsk) =>
    sandelys.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
            .Select(g => g.MinBy(s => s.Price))
            .ToList();
```

If you can't use MoreLINQ, you could order each group by price and take the first result from each ordered group, but it's uglier and less efficient:

```
protected List<Sandelys> FormuotiUzsakyma(List<Sandelys> sandelys, Uzsakymas uzsk) =>
    sandelys.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(s => s.Price).First())
            .ToList();
```

As an aside, you don't appear to be using your `uzsk` parameter at all.